# update script stored procedure sql server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am fairly new to posting questions i greatly appreciate your support.
I wanted to write a proc to update my table `testAd`.

A replace function could do it but I have almost a million records to update and I am trying to use stored procedure.

Could you have a look at what I have started? Thank you I appreciate it. I should come up with something by end of day today..a kind of  tough situation. I tried the one below it doesn't seem to be working.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[testAd]
AS
DECLARE @ci  VARCHAR (255)
UPDATE Stage.TestAdd
SET @ci=AddressOne
SET @ci= CASE @ci
 WHEN 'Des Moines'  THEN 'IA' 
 WHEN 'Seattle'    THEN 'WA'
 WHEN 'Pheonix'    THEN 'Az'   
 WHEN 'Phx'   THEN 'Az'
 .
 . 
 ELSE @ci
```

END

Comment: I should add this  ..the cities are merged in the following format,"1234 snew wy seattle" they are not by themselves  they are attached to other strings.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to update a value stored in one field from [city] to matching [state]

Instead of using a long case statement you can use a table variable with valid pairs and then join with that table in update

something like here:

```
declare @cityInState as table(city varchar(50), state char(2))
insert into @cityInState 
values
    ('Des Moines','IA') 
    ,('Seattle', 'WA')
    ,('Pheonix','Az')   
    ,('Phx','Az')
    -- etc ...

update yt
set 
    fieldToUpdate = cis.state
from 
    yourTable yt
    inner join @cityInState cit on yt.fieldToUpdate = cit.city
```

**WARNING**: that will replace the city value with the state, so only run this if that is what you want.

It would be really better to add this as an extra field (ideally a reference to a lookup table) as after the update you will **loose** the city info.

Comment: Hi @Kristof, I am very grateful for your answer.But I have to tell you this that there is only one field which has the city in its address field and its got to be replaced in the same field"1234 s ohio st Seattle". I hope i didnt confuse you.Thanks again for your replies..I  appreciate it .

Comment: @user1689111 the code above will do just that. To use it just replace fieldToUpdate with your real filed name and yourTable with the real table name

Comment: @user1689111 and of course you can put this code insite a stored procedure

Comment: @Kristof..Again I am very thankful for understanding my urgency and providing me with your replies.

Comment: But I just tested it it seems to be not working,I did just like you advised me to do so....

Comment: But I just tested  it seems to be not working,I did just like you advised me to do so  Hey..Thanks again

Comment: Hey Guys I hope you help me out on this I am a kind of reaching  deadline kind of thing which realy may hurt me...Thanks again guys

Comment: @user1689111 post the code that you tried to run if you are still interested